# Connect remote server for logging using Log4J

Tags: java, log4j

I want To Connect to the remote server to write my log files using Log4J Socket Appender
My log.properties file is as below

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, BLAH

# to connect to the remote server
log4j.appender.BLAH=org.apache.log4j.net.SocketAppender

# set set that layout to be SimpleLayout
log4j.appender.BLAH.layout=org.apache.log4j.SimpleLayout

#log4j.appender.BLAH.File= admin.log

log4j.appender.BLAH.Port= xx
log4j.appender.BLAH.RemoteHost= <remoteIp>
```

I tried connecting localhost too with port number 22 and 8080

I am making a mistake some where in the connection .
I get the following error

```
log4j:ERROR Could not connect to remote log4j server at [localhost]. We will try again later.
```

or 
Give me any suggestions to write the log files in a remote server machine.

Comment: have you tested the remote server accept requests in the given port?

Comment: As of now .. I want it to work when i give localhost for testing purpose.
I do connect the remote via sftp

Comment: The flow will be the remote machine(in your case for testing purpose the localhost itself) will have a program listening to a given port. The log4j will connect to this port for writing logs. Do you have a listener mechanism in place in which listens to the port?. I mean are you running a org.apache.log4j.net.SocketServer instance in your remote(or localhost) machine?

Comment: is remote logging not possible if we don deploy a listener in the server ..(the machine in which we wish to write our logs)???

Answer (score 5):

You should have a server running which listens to a given port. The log4j should connect to this server for logging.

Type the following in command prompt to start the listener

Java org.apache.log4j.net.SimpleSocketServer 4712 PATH_TO_THE_FILE\log4jServer.properties

Eg

> java org.apache.log4j.net.SimpleSocketServer 4712 C:\log4j-server.properties

log4j-server.properties may contain something like this.

```
> log4j-server.properties will contain normal configuration of log4j.
> log4j.rootLogger=debug, stdout
> log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
> log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
> log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
> log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%t %-5p %c{2} - %m%n
```

In the client side, your log4j config will look like this

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, BLAH  
# to connect to the remote server 
log4j.appender.BLAH=org.apache.log4j.net.SocketAppender  
# set set that layout to be SimpleLayout 
log4j.appender.BLAH.layout=org.apache.log4j.SimpleLayout  
#log4j.appender.BLAH.File= admin.log  
log4j.appender.BLAH.Port= 4712 
log4j.appender.BLAH.RemoteHost=10.225.226.58
```

Replace the IP and Port(without conflicting the standard ports) as per your configuration. 
Hope this would help.

Answer (score 3):

Port 22 and 8080 are usually used by SSH and HTTP respectively. The `SocketAppender` is expecting to talk to a `SocketNode` using its own TCP-based protocol. So you need to start one up, on a different port of your choice.

Note that when you try to log to a remote server, you'll need to have that port open on the firewall.

Comment: Can u pl tel me how to set up a log4J SocketNode . My project is not a web application.
I want to write logs into a machine say to maintain an extra Backup.

Comment: I wouldn't bother if I were you. I'd set up an rsync task to copy the logs across, periodically, instead.